# How to get Transaction Id from sandbox paypal

Tags: http, grails, paypal

This is my question .

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="opacity:0;height:42px;background:red;left:0;top:0; width:100%;margin:0px;position:absolute;">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="business" value="walapaybusiness@gmail.com">
              <input type="hidden" id="paypal_text" name="return" value="${request.serverUrl}/marketProducts/productBuySuccess?productId=1&flag=10"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="${request.serverUrl}/dudewala/paymentSuccess" />
              <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
              <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Dude dollar">
              <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
              <input class="paypalBtn" type="image" style="height:42px;width:100%;  " src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
              &nbsp;
</form>
```

This is my form for paypal sandbox mode and this is my success url from paypal

`${request.serverUrl}/marketProducts/productBuySuccess`

Here is it possible to attach transaction id from paypal?

May be the expected URL will look like

```
${request.serverUrl}/marketProducts/productBuySuccess?transactionId=123456789000
```

So I can fetch the transaction `id` as `params.transactionId`

I am doing this in grails so It will be great if you can give my answer in grails

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal send you `Transaction ID` with the `txn_id` name. You can also use others, like `payer_id`, etc...

Comment: :how paypal send? am using **sandbox paypal** .what parameter i should add??can you write the code and explain?

Comment: When PayPal send you back informations in your URL. You can read variable `txn_id` with the Transaction ID code.

Comment: see Croises,my return success url is defined in my code itself   **  <input type="hidden" id="paypal_text" name="return" value="${request.serverUrl}/marketProducts/productBuySuccess?productId=1&flag=10"/> ** here am not getting any variable name txn_id.PLease look my code above and give a clear idea.i am definning my success url

Comment: Yes !, You have to use: `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.yourserver.com/marketProducts/productBuySuccess">`. No need to ask for infos, PayPal send all back.

Comment: so when the transaction is complete it automatically eneters in to my success url that i had mentioned in my previus comment,so how can i add a parameter in that?

Comment: so in my controller action if i write like this **params.txn_id** will i get paypal transaction id??

Comment: If you need custom and invoice parameters, you can add `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="YOURNUM>'; <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="OTHERNUMBER">`. You don't have a lot of parameters you can use. You can see [Here: PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/)

Comment: Yes, you will get paypal transaction id like that !

Comment: one more doubt ,<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.yourserver.com/marketProducts/productBuySuccess"> am not able to return to my site,but if i give like this **<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourserver.com/marketProducts/productBuySuccess"** its having one return button ,so when i click i can redirect to my site,but when i gave your url i dont have that **return button**

Comment: you understood my question??

Comment: You can use `return` for your page after payment and `cancel_return` for the page when user cancel.

Comment: so how can i give 2 name to an input type??,<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="yourserver.com/marketProducts/productBuySuccess"> OR    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="yourserver.com/marketProducts/productBuySuccess">

Comment: No, but you can use 2 `<input type`. But only one for each name. Don't use the same page for notify_url (internal use only) and for return or cancel (user can see them)

Comment: when i give notify_url then only i will get transaction id from paypal so if i give paypal site not returning to my website it need the input type name to be return

Comment: Crosis where i will use notify_url then?

Comment: Please, read the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/). `notify_url` is just used from PayPal server to your server, without user interaction.

Comment: Read the 4th answer on the top. Good luck!